# Initialize JsonB configuration once

Tags: jax-rs, quarkus

I am customizing Jsonb using a `ContextResolver<Jsonb>` as in the example below.

It works correctly, but I have seen that the method gets invoked on every call which seems to me a waste of performance. ¿Isn't there a way to initialize Jsonb only once?

```java
    @Override
    public Jsonb getContext(Class type) {
        final JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig()
            .withDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault())
            .withSerializers(
                new UserSerializer(),
                new PaperSerializer()
            );
        return JsonbBuilder.create(config);
    }
```

PS: I am aware I can setup serializers using `@JsonbTypeSerializer`. I am not looking for alternative ways to do the same configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the instance of `Jsonb` in your context resolver yourself. Probably with a volatile and a double checked locking to be on the safe side.

I'm not entirely sure if it's a bug or a feature (i.e. if it's the desired behavior that you have to do it yourself and that it's delegated to the `ContextResolver` for each call).

See the implementation here: https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/providers/json-binding/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/jsonb/AbstractJsonBindingProvider.java#L27 .

I'll check with the RESTEasy developers.

Comment: I created https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/4048 so that we properly document it.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a new way to customize JSON-B with Quarkus, it is documented here: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json-guide#configuring-json-support

So the correct answer is now to implements a `JsonbConfigCustomizer`.

The following should works for your use case:

```
import io.quarkus.jsonb.JsonbConfigCustomizer;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbConfig;
import javax.json.bind.serializer.JsonbSerializer;

@Singleton
public class MyJsonbConfigCustomizer implements JsonbConfigCustomizer {

    public void customize(JsonbConfig config) {
        config.withDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault())
              .withSerializers(
                  new UserSerializer(),
                  new PaperSerializer()
        );
    }
}
```